# Using Stream Cache With Apache Camel

Tags: java, caching, apache-camel

I m using stream caching with this example below.

I have three routes.

First, I used the split streaming with a token "\n", reading a file splitted by line.

```
     <route id="SPLIT-FLOW" streamCache="true">
        <from uri="file:src/data/forSplitCaching?noop=true"/>
        <split streaming="true">
            <tokenize token="\n"/>
            <to uri="direct:PROCESS-BUSINESS"/>
        </split>
    </route>
```

Then I made a business process :

```
    <route id="PROCESS-BUSINESS" streamCache="true">
        <from uri="direct:PROCESS-BUSINESS"/>
        <bean ref="ProcessBusiness" method="dealRecord"/>
        <to uri="direct:STREAM-CACHING"/>
    </route>

    public class ProcessBusiness {

     public String dealRecord(@Body String body){
     System.out.println(body);
     return body;
}
```

And Finally,

```
    <route id="STREAM-CACHING">
        <from uri="direct:STREAM-CACHING"/>
        <bean ref="ProcessStreamCaching" method="usingStream"/>
        <setHeader headerName="CamelFileName">
            <simple>${header.CamelFileName}.${header.CamelSplitIndex}   </simple>
        </setHeader>
        <to uri="file:src/out"/>
    </route>

   public class ProcessStreamCaching {

     public String usingStream(Exchange exchange){
     Object o = exchange.getIn().getBody(StreamCache.class);
     return  o.toString();
    }
```

I wanted to get the whole file in this process (`ProcessStreamCaching`).

How can i correctly use the stream cache ?

The file before splitting contain :

```
XXXXX
YYYYY
ZZZZZ
AAAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
SSQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ
ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
Z
```

I thought that the stream cache was able to put all line of the file in a cache, and i can retrieve these lines.

How can I see what is placed in the cache ?

I thought when i add  `streamCache="true"` at this route `<route id="SPLIT-FLOW" >`, each line of the splitter will be placed on the cache. (or may be the whole file)

At the last process `ProcessStreamCaching`, if I wanted to reload the  `inputStream` from the beginning , but at this process i can't because i have already read the `inputStream`.

I want to keep reading the file with streaming line per line, but at on process  I need to read for exemple the first line , that s why i wanted to use the stream cache , who allows me to browse the file from the beginning.

May be I misunderstand the Stream Cache.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to parse a stream twice (or more times), you can convert it to String before and parse it as many times as necessary.

Please check similar question here: [Exchange.getIn().getBody() returns empty string in camel on second call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048031/exchange-getin-getbody-returns-empty-string-in-camel-on-second-call)

Comment: It s not the purpose to use the Stream more times, because the stream cache is able to reload the Stream, and i don't know how to use it @Sergey

Comment: Do you have an example of the stream cache please in which you store some date then you retrieve it. thxs

Comment: My answer is not how to use stream cache, but it gives you an alternative solution to your problem (...browse the file from the beginning). However if  you are keen on using stream cache, just check the documentation in http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html

Comment: I can t convert a file with a fileSize > 1 GO to a String, that s why i want to use the stream cache , i ve already checked the documentation , unfortunatly i find how to implement a stream cache and not how to use it and check the data of the stream cache.

Comment: If you try to parse GBs of data several times, I am pretty sure that stream cache wont work neither. Consider using of a DB or search engine