# Camel message is null the second time is printed

Tags: java, apache-camel, message

The problem is very simple which the below code explain

```
System.out.println(exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class)); // Shows some data
System.out.println(exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class)); // Empty
```

Comment: Feels like `getIn` is some kind of enumerator? So the first time you call it, you get the data you want from the correct pos, second time you've skipped ahead.

Comment: Or a stream. If it is a stream then enable stream caching on the context or route level to avoid this kind of issue. But note the addtl. memory that might be required.

Comment: We need more information to answer!

Comment: @jhamon Its a camel exchange

Comment: @AdamKortylewicz What kind of information u want?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048031/exchange-getin-getbody-returns-empty-string-in-camel-on-second-call

Already Answered